# Sidebar Not Working

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new at web design and cannot seem to get a side bar working for my website.

Basically I got my files and code from [www.berriart.com/sidr/](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) and did exactly what they asked, however the side navigation bar is still not working.

All that comes up is blue hyperlinks under my banner, you can see it here: [www.justpaste.it/lzhg.](http://justpaste.it/lzhg)

I have pasted my html underneath if anyone could please help me that would be wonderful!

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascripts/sidr/stylesheets/jquery.sidr.dark.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
         <div class="logo"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="navbar">
    <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Toggle menu</a>

<div id="sidr">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr();
});
</script>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <div class="posts">1</div>
         <div class="posts">2</div>
         <div class="posts">3</div>
         <div class="posts">4</div>
         <div class="posts">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">asdfafdsasfsdasfad</div>
    </div>
 <script src="javascripts/sidr/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Comment: Whenever you use open source anything, make sure it's being actively developed. Sidr hasn't been touched in two years. You can find this out by clicking the "Fork me on Github" link in the top right. Check out frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation and PureCSS to get going on something more dependable. They all come with responsive navigation components.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add jQuery.

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that would do it.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply, works great!